# Node.JS & Neo4j CRUD Methods

Tags: node.js, neo4j, crud

I'm very new to node.js. I'm working to build a simple CRUD app with a neo4j database. I see examples all over the web for node + mongo, but very very very little for node + neo4j.

I have the Create and Read aspects of CRUD working, but I'm going crazy trying to find any documentation or examples for the Update and Delete methods.

Thank you for any coding help or for pointing me in the direction of sound documentation/examples.

This is what I have so far for Get and Post methods:

```
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
    session
            .run('MATCH(b:Beer) RETURN b Order By b.name ASC')
            .then(function(result){
                    var beerArr = [];
                    result.records.forEach(function(record){
                            beerArr.push({
                                    id: record._fields[0].identity.low,
                                    name: record._fields[0].properties.name,
                                    ABV: record._fields[0].properties.ABV,
                                    kor: record._fields[0].properties.kor
                            });
                    });
            .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
           });
    });


    app.post('/beer/add',function(req, res){

    var beername = req.body.beername;
    var abv = req.body.abv;
    var ibu = req.body.ibu;
    var kor = req.body.kor;
    var beertypename = req.body.beertypename;
    var breweryname = req.body.breweryname;

    session
            .run('Match (bt:BeerType {name: {beertypenameParam}}), (bry:Brewery {name: {brewerynameParam}}) Create (bt)<-[r:IS_A]-(b:Beer {name: {beernameParam},ABV:{abvParam},IBU:{ibuParam},kor:{korParam}})<-[r2:BREWS]-(bry) Set b.date = apoc.date.format(timestamp(),"ms","MM/dd/yyyy"),b.Uid = apoc.create.uuid() Return bt,b,bry', {beertypenameParam:beertypename,brewerynameParam:breweryname,beernameParam:beername, abvParam:abv, ibuParam:ibu, korParam:kor})

            .then(function(result){
                    res.redirect('/');

                    session.close();
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
            });

          res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you move to Node.js but were already using Neo4j? Otherwise what made you choose Neo4j? I struggled with Neo4j on one project. The deal-breaker for me was the fact that nodes and relations are "flat" - they cannot contain nested properties. This meant that I had to either to build out nodes to store "dumb" data, or encode and decode the nested properties on every call. This is why people use Mongo, though if you have relational data, it's really not a good fit. I eventually moved to Arangodb and have been very happy

Comment: Great question @Codebling, I work with Neo4j at work and had worked through a Node/Neo4j tutorial but the tut left out the UD of CRUD. I've since added the UD and haven't had an issue with needing nested properties but can see how that's a deal breaker for some.